# Unmatched Air Traffic Control (UATC) Voice Recognition Option not visible

Tags: android, unmatched-air-traffic-control

In the gameplay settings, Audio, there is no checkbox to enable voice recognition.  There are only two choices, Pilot Voices and Subtitles.

**Configuration**

- Samsung Galaxy S7, Android 8.0.0 (API 26), last version for this
  phone Android
- Language: English (United States)
- UATC v 2022.06
- UATC language:English
- Permissions granted to UATC: Microphone
- Microphone/headphones work in other applications.
- Using a Google Play account.

What's missing?

Thanks!